# Can´t add items to UICollectionView inside UIView xib

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

### Objective

I wanna place my (BusinessViewTableHeader: UIView) as tableView header:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = BusinessViewTableHeader.instanceFromNib() as! BusinessViewTableHeader
```

Inside BusinessViewTableHeader there is a UICollectionView which are supposed to display images when swiped, much like the Tinder app.

This is my UIView subclass:

```
class BusinessViewTableHeader: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "BusinessImageCollectionCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "BusinessImageCollectionCell")
    }

    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "BusinessViewTableHeader", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }
    
    ....
}

extension BusinessViewTableHeader: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    ....
}
```

### Problem

I have a custom UIView xib containing a UICollectionView. The problem is that I can´t add any cells (items) to the UICollectionView. I can add items to my other UICollectionView which are placed inside a UIViewController. The first image is showing the properties for the UICollectionView inside a UIViewController, the second image is showing the UICollectionView inside a UIView xib.

[![UICollectionView in UIViewController][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFCeG.png

[![UICollectionView in UIView xib][2][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKU6z.png

### Question

Why am I not able to add items to the UICollectionView inside the UIView xib? How?

Comment: Do you have a UIViewController connected to your xib with datasource and delegate to your UICollectionView?

Comment: I just updated my question with some code. Im subclassing UIView, not UIViewController. Is that even possible with subviews? Im creating a table view header view.

Comment: Please don't include the answer in your question. If an answer solved your issue, mark the answer as accepted; you can also post your own answer if you resolved your problem yourself. Thank you.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can't have UICollectionViewCell when the UICollectionView is on a Nib. What you need to do is to create the UICollectionViewCell as another nib and get it registered in the class that you are using for your CollectionView.

Create a new nib, drag a UICollectionViewCell inside it, and do something like this in the class that works with your UICollectionView.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    let nibName = UINib(nibName: "ClassCollectionCell", bundle:nil)
    collectionView.registerNib(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell")
}
```

Remember you can add a custom class to the UICollectionViewCell so you can pass dynamic data to it.

Comment: Thats exactly how I did if you take a look above in my code.

Comment: @rilar Do you have a nib file with a UICollectionVIewCell in it?

Comment: Stupid misstake, I forgot: self.collectionView.dataSource = self. You where right though, thx!

Comment: how to connect iboutlet of collectionviewcell from xib to custom class of collectionview @Pato Salazar

Comment: Why do you need to do that....are you trying to trigger a method that exists in you collection view class??...

Answer (score 2):

Adding cells in a xib is not supported. If you must use a xib file, then you will need a separate xib which contains the UICollectionView cell. Storyboards may be a better solution.

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. UICollectionView has specific means for creating headers which uses the datasource and delegate. Collection views are good for displaying items in a grid layout or other complex arrangements.

If all you need is to display a list of rows, then a UITableViewController might be an easier alternative.

Whatever the case, it is probably better to use a storyboard instead of a xib, and to subclass the UICollectionViewController or UITableViewController, rather than a subview.

Your custom class name can be entered in the identity inspector for the UIViewController or UIView:

[image: UIViewController identity inspector]

[image: UIView identity inspector]

Comment: I updated my question with an 'Objective'. I don´t know how to explain it more clearly then that. The images I attached are just to show that when placing a UICollectionView inside a UIView from xib it´s not possible to add any items, or cells, to it. Why is that? How do I manage this? I really wanna have tableView.tableHeaderView as a xib file.

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 3.0** register nib with following method-

```
let nibName = UINib(nibName: "FruitCell", bundle:nil)
collectionView.register(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CellIdentifier")
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift 3.0**

first Create Xibfile of UIView

```
import UIKit

class SubCatagoryListView:UIView , UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    @IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnClose: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var subCategoryListCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        subCategoryListCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "SubcatagoryListCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SubcatagoryListCollectionViewCell")
        mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        mainView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    static func subCatagoryListView() -> SubCatagoryListView? {
        let arr = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SubCatagoryListView", owner: self, options: nil)
        if arr != nil {
            if arr!.count > 0 {
                if let view = arr![0] as? SubCatagoryListView {

                    return view;
                }
            }
        }

        return nil;
    }





    @IBAction func btnBackgroundTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
         self.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    @IBAction func btnCloseTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SubcatagoryListCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SubcatagoryListCollectionViewCell

        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let cellsize = CGSize(width: (subCategoryListCollectionView.bounds.size.width/3) - 10, height: 50)
        return cellsize
    }


}
```

After Create new CollectionViewCell Xib file

```
import UIKit

class SubcatagoryListCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

}
```

after create both file i am load xib on my storybord

```
var subcatagoryXib:SubCatagoryListView?

override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        if let subcategoryView = SubCatagoryListView.subCatagoryListView()
        {

            subcatagoryXib = subcategoryView
        }

    }
 @IBAction func btnAddInterestTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if subcatagoryXib != nil
        {
            self.subcatagoryXib!.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width , height: self.view.frame.height)
            self.view.addSubview(self.subcatagoryXib!)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as @Pato's answer, but here is a more thorough tutorial for `how to add a customized UICollectionViewCell inside a Xib file` from @aestusLabs on Medium. It's a 3-5 min reading, I personally find it very helpful. It basically tells you to create another customized UICollectionViewCell with .xib, and register it in your "level 1" cell's `awakeFromNib()`.

https://medium.com/@aestusLabs/adding-a-uicollectionviews-to-a-custom-uitableviewcell-xib-tutorial-swift-4-xcode-9-2-1ec9ce4095d3